# capistrano 3 not compiled assets missing in public/assets directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, capistrano3

I have a number of assets in my rails public/assets directory that I do not want compiled - specifically all the image files I want to use in my ember app.  However, I cannot figure out how to get capistrano to deploy them.  They are checked in to the public/assets directory but they do not appear in the deployed shared or release directories on my server.  In fact I searched the whole capistrano directory tree on my server and the assets are nowhere to be found.  I have confirmed that the assets are in git for the branch that capistrano is deploying.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to configure capistrano / capistrano-rails to allow me to use git source controlled files under public/assets, however, it did work to create an img directory under public and put the images there in git.  That avoids the asset compilation process and the md5 hashes for the images and works well with ember.